# How is memory set aside when an object is created out of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I read that `__init__` doesn't create the object(sets aside memory).

I couldn't find who does the actual object creation.
How does this object creation happens internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `__new__`.

From a Python point of view, what happens is something like the following, assuming you have a class, `A`, that inherits directly from `object`:

- `A.__new__` method gets called
- `object.__new__` gets called, with `cls=A`
- `A.__init__` method gets called, with arguments forwarded from your `A.__new__`

Example:

```
class A():

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'__new__ called with args {args} and kwargs {kwargs}')
        return super().__new__(cls)  # object.__new__

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'__init__ called with args {args} and kwargs {kwargs}')
        # args are discarded
        for key, arg in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, arg)

a_instance = A('arg', kwarg=1)
a_instance.kwarg
```

Output:

```
__new__ called with args ('arg',) and kwargs {'kwarg': 1}
__init__ called with args ('arg',) and kwargs {'kwarg': 1}
1
```

In general, there is no need to do anything with `__new__`, *because Python objects are usually mutable*, and so there is no distinction between initialising instance attributes and modifying them.

The main use case of overriding `__new__`, in my experience, is when you inherit from immutable types, such as `tuple`. In such cases, you *must* initialise all instance attributes at creation, and therefore `__init__` is too late.

Comment: Is the definition and call to `__new__` implicit?

Comment: @ak_app Yes, when you call `A(*args, **kwargs)`, you are in fact calling `A.__new__(*args, **kwargs)`. `args` and `kwargs` are forwarded to `A.__init__`.

Comment: You have a `# tuple.__new__` comment, but you're not actually inheriting from `tuple`.

Comment: @user2357112 Fixed, I considered using a `tuple` subclass example, then discarded it, but forgot to change the comment.

Answer (score 2):

When you type something like `MyClass()` in Python, Python runtime will call `__new__` on `MyClass`, which should construct an object; this will be followed by invoking `__init__` on the newly constructed object. Thus, `__new__` is called "constructor", and `__init__` an "initialiser". This sequence is coded outside Python (in C, in case of CPython). Visit Python documentation to read more on [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) and [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__).

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

As a short answer, the method which creates the object is  `__new__`  and `__init__` just initializes the created object.

### Long answer

However, keep reading if you want to get a deeper insight into what's happening when an object is going to be created in python.

---

In python 2.x there were two types of classes in python old-style and new-style classes.

```
class C: # A old-style class sample 
     pass
```

---

```
class C(object): # A old-style class sample 
     pass
```

In old-style classes, there was no `__new__`  method so `__init__` was the constructor.
However, in python 3.x, just new-style class remains ( Independent of whatever kind of definition you choose for your class, It'll be inherited from the base class "Object"). In new-style classes both `__new__` and `__init__`  methods are available. `__new__` and `__init__` is the constructor and the initializer respectively and you're permitted to override both of them (be cautious, generally you don't need to override `__new__` method expect in some cases like defining meta classes and etc. so don't manipulate it if it's not necessary.)
Finally, when an object is going to be created, the constructor will be called before initializer.

```
class A(object):  # -> don't forget the object specified as base

def __new__(cls):
    print "A.__new__ called"
    return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

def __init__(self):
    print "A.__init__ called"

A()
```

The output will be:

```
A.__new__ called
A.__init__ called
```